# Vuetify VCheckbox emitts event "update:modelValue" after setValue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

When I set a value for checkbox I got a warning: **[Vue warn]: Component emitted event "update:modelValue" but it is neither declared in the emits option nor as an "onUpdate:modelValue" prop**.

test.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { VForm } from 'vuetify/components'

const privacyPolicies = ref<boolean>(false)
</script>

<template id="register-form">
  <VCardText>
    <VForm
      id="registerForm"
      class="mt-4"
    >
      <VRow>
        <VCol cols="12">
          <VCheckbox
            v-model="privacyPolicies"
            data-privacy-policy
          />
        </VCol>
      </VRow>
    </VForm>
  </VCardText>
</template>
```

test.test.ts

```
import TestRegister from '@/pages/components/test.vue'
...

describe.concurrent('Test.vue', () => {
  let wrapper: VueWrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(TestRegister, {
      global: {
        plugins: [
          createVuetify({ components, directives }),
        ],
      },
    })
  })

  it('test something', async () => {
    const checkBoxSelector = '[data-privacy-policy]'

    await wrapper.findComponent<typeof VCheckbox>(checkBoxSelector).setValue(true)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[wrapper](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setvalue) `setValue` is for HTML input elements, not components. VCheckbox is a VueComponent so you probably want to use `await wrapper.findComponent<typeof VCheckbox>(checkBoxSelector).value = true`;

if you want to set the HTML input value you can also:
`await wrapper.get('.text-field__input').setValue(true)`

you can find the issue here:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/1883

Comment: I tired your first solution (await wrapper.findComponent<typeof VCheckbox>(PrivacyPoliciesCheckBoxSelector).value = true) and i get ERROR: Invalid assignment target. Actually in my real code i do two things .setValue(true) on Component and .setChecked() on Input in order to make privacyPolicies.value = true, then i can submit the form (submit button is enabled then). It works but i got that warning.